# How to reinstall sound?

Tags: linux, audio, sound-card

I'm not even sure if sound was working after the install, I have installed things and 'apt-get upgrade' since then.

When I realized I had no sound, I tried installing 'emu10k1' from this list: http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Creative_Labs

But it didn't work, or maybe I made a mistake.

I think I should let Ubuntu autodetect sound and reinstall it, to see what happens, but how do I do that?

Any other info is greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm on Ubuntu 12, as host. My sound card is "SoundBlaster Live! 5.1"

Note 2: I've been using linux for some time but only as VM's. I'm moving from windows 7.

**UPDATE**

Now I'm following this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

I'm stuck with the driver version, which is different from the other things:

```
!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     1.0.24
Library version:    1.0.25
Utilities version:  1.0.25
```

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=ddac5968c48099411b3ca2cd69d982dabd5e2c2b

Comment: Did you installed alsa-utils ?

Comment: @Ivan yes. Now I'm following this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure, and I found that my driver has a different version. I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling the whole SO =/